# Isn't jquery-fx.js already part of jquery.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I saw in a project that `jquery-fx.js` is being linked, but isn't it for `show(), hide(), animate()` etc, so `jquery.js` already has them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment, `jquery-fx.js` is actually part of jRails.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [effects](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js) was pulled into jQuery core some time ago, you can see that chunk of the API here: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

If they're referring to a *different* file that just happens to be called `jquery-fx.js`...well, there's no way to tell what's happening there unless you post the contents of that file.

In case your curious, it was still called `fx.js` as recent as 1.3.2 (if you're including individual files/modules, instead of the whole library as most do).  You can see what the code looked like here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.3.2/src

Comment: Thanks.  It is strange that the project is linking to jquery.js and jquery-fx.js and the jquery.js shows at the top of the file that it is jQuery 1.3.1, but in that file, I can find the definitions of `show()`, `hide()`, and `animate()` etc. It is the same situation in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.js

Comment: @Jian - In that case it's just overriding the same functions, waste of bandwidth really :)

Comment: so the standard is, if it is linking to jquery.js version 1.3.1 (as in the one hosted by Google), then it shouldn't be linking to jquery-fx.js as well?

Comment: it is very strange that jquery-fx.js doesn't have the definition of animate()... the beginning of the file is like this: `(function($){$.ec=$.ec||{};$.extend($.ec,{save:function(el,set){for(var i=0;i<set.length;i++){ ...`

Comment: looks like this `jquery-fx.js` is for jRails usage: using jQuery in Ruby on Rails... probably a standard release of the jRails code: http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/01/14/replace-prototype-with-jquery-on-rails/